# PHP file upload not working

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a picture but it always showing me the error. I think i have done everything it needs to upload a picture. Any help would be appreciated.

### html:

```
<form action="../Code Files/User.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div id="photo_settings2" style="margin-left:74px;">
        <img id="Picture" src="../../img/User No-Frame.png"/>       
    </div>

    <br><br><br><br>

    <div id='Upload_Panel' style="margin-left: 32px;">
        <input name='file' type='file' id='file_browse' onchange="readURL(this,'Picture')" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
    </div>

    <div id="delete" style="margin-top: -40px; margin-left: 198px; cursor: pointer">
        <img src="../../img/Delete_Panel.png">
    </div>

    <div style="margin-left:144px; margin-top:-15px"></div>

    <br><br> 
    </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

### php code:

```
$UploadDirectory    = '/www/';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['file'], $UploadDirectory))
{
    die('Success! File Uploaded.');
}

else
{
    die('error uploading File!');
}
```

Comment: Make sure to check the permissions of the folder you are uploading to. They need to be enabled for write privileges.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: this error "error uploading File!" when i put $_FILES['file']['file'] in else part it saved to the database.

Comment: No no space @Roopendra

Comment: Okay I just cross check :)

Comment: Do take the time to [`read the manual`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], basename($_FILES['file']['name'])))
{
    die('Success! File Uploaded.');
}
else
{
    die('error uploading File!');
}
```

**Edit**: I've changed the destination argument - now uploaded file will appear next to your php file. Remember about target folder permissions.

Comment: Also read: http://php.net/move_uploaded_file and http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: cahnging this  works for me $_FILES['file']['file']. one problem i having now. it is not showing on the www folder? any help?

Answer (score 0):

### Working Code:

```
  $UploadDirectory = '/wamp/www/img/Users/Users/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory))
  {
      die('Success! File Uploaded.');
  }

  else
  {
      die('error uploading File!');
  }
```