# how to get picture filename from database?

Tags: php, sql

I want to get the database picture path so that i can used it and store the same file-name path in the image folder so both can be matched up. Actually i am using a unique-id so that pictures have unique names but don't know how to use it rightly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$insert = "UPDATE USER_LOGIN SET PICTURE = '".uniqid().$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE USERNAME = '".$_COOKIE['username']."'";

$result = oci_parse($con, $insert);


// Executes a statement.

$check = oci_execute($result);


$UploadDirectory = '/wamp/www/img/Users/Users/'.$row['PICTURE'];
```

Comment: Usually when a file is [`uploaded`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file), two variables are used. One for the upload path, and one for the file itself. Both of these variables can be concatenated and assigned to a new variable, where it can be used thereafter as a reference thereafter. Yet, from what I saw in [`another one of your questions`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21949414/) (and [`your answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21949961/)), you could use `$UploadDirectory`

Comment: u mean i use `$UploadDirectory` to insert into the database?

Comment: Yes, that's usually how many do it. Give it a try and see.

Comment: okay. was actually doing the same but i think first i need to ulpoad the file to the folder then insert because (null) was storing in the database. will give a try. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Working Solution:

```
              if($row)
              {

                    $Filename = uniqid().$_FILES['file']['name'];
                    $DirectoryPath = '/wamp/www/img/Users/Users/'.$Filename;
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $DirectoryPath))
                    {

                        $insert = "UPDATE USER_LOGIN SET PICTURE = '".$Filename."' WHERE USERNAME = '".$_COOKIE['username']."'";
                        $result = oci_parse($con, $insert);

                        // Executes a statement.
                        $check = oci_execute($result);

                        if($check)
                        {
                            echo "Saved";

                            // Commit the changes to the table.
                            oci_commit($con);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            // Rollback changes to table.
                            oci_rollback($con);
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //die('error uploading File!');
                    }
              }
```

Comment: I wonder what happens if I upload a file named `', PASSWORD='dummy`